# Try to access in flutter a map inside a map from json but won´t work

Tags: json, flutter, decode

i call an api with

```
Future<ApiData> fetchData() async {
  final response = await http
      .get(Uri.parse(
          'https://apilink.com'));
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    Map<String, dynamic> jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
    return ApiData.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  }
```

and have a json file like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "base_data": {
      "US": {
        "org_data": {
          "country_full_name": "UNITED STATES",
          "size": "large"
        },
        "user_data": {
          "amount": 1.0,
          "owned_in_total_euro": 100
        }
      },
      "DE": {
        "org_data": {
          "country_full_name": "Germany",
          "size": "medium"
        },
        "user_data": {
          "amount": 5.0,
          "owned_in_total_euro": 400
        }
      }
    },
    "calc_data": {
      "country": {
        "United States": 1.0
        "Germany": 5.0
        "Poland": 4.5
      },
      "currency": {
        "USD": 1.0
        "EUR": 2.0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In jsonReponse is a map with 1 item => 0: "data" -> Map (2 items)
This is a map with maps inside with other maps or lists inside and they are dynamice like this:

```
Map
  Map1
    MapABC
    MapXYZ
      List
  Map2
    List
  MapX
```

I tried a lot of things like this but nothing worked:

```
//data map
Map<String, dynamic> jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);

//base_data & calc_data inside data
Map<dynamic, dynamic> jsonResponse2 = Map.from(jsonResponse);
```

Question:
How can I access this in flutter?
Do you have any examples of info on this for me?
I tryed a lot with stuff I found in google and the decode-help but can´t find out how to process a  (dynamic)-map in a map.

Thanks in advance
Patrick

Update:
I added this to my model:

```
 @JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class BackendCalcData {
  List<BackendCalcDataCountry>? backendCountry;
  List<BackendCalcDataCurrency>? backendCurrency;

  BackendCalcData({
    List<BackendCalcDataCountry>? backendCountry,
    List<BackendCalcDataCurrency>? backendCurrency,
  });

  factory BackendCalcData.empty() {
    return BackendCalcData();
  }

  factory BackendCalcData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$BackendCalcDataFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$BackendCalcDataToJson(this);
}

@JsonSerializable()
class BackendCalcDataCountry {
  String countryName;
  double countryRatio;

  BackendCalcDataCountry({
    this.countryName = "",
    this.countryRatio = 0,
  });

  factory BackendCalcDataCountry.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$BackendCalcDataCountryFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$BackendCalcDataCountryToJson(this);
}

@JsonSerializable()
class BackendCalcDataCurrency {
  String currencyCode;
  double currencyRatetoEuro;

  BackendCalcDataCurrency({
    this.currencyCode = "",
    this.currencyRatetoEuro = 0,
  });

  factory BackendCalcDataCurrency.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$BackendCalcDataCurrencyFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$BackendCalcDataCurrencyToJson(this);
}
```

And got the generated code.

Comment: The correct way is create a model of this json, follow this example:
https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/json

Comment: Thx - I did this and have now my classes and to generated Code from JsonSerializable - how I put the json-file in there? I added to code in my question above

Comment: Now just call BackendCalcDataCurrency.fromJson(writeYourJsonHere)